# VS Code - Angular 1/TypeScript - "angular" is not recognized when removing /// reference

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I decided to experiment a bit with a seed project for angular using TypeScript.
According to [vs code docs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vscode/2015/07/06/visual-studio-code-es6/) (see second headline) I can drop /// references at the top of my .ts files, and Visual Studio Code should still give me proper intellicense if I have correct `tsconfig.json` file in place. Well, I do, and unless I place the `reference` thing my `angular` variable is not getting recognized.

Here is a [link to the project](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/ng-boilerplate) that I'm testing with.
See `src/client/home/home.ts` file.

PS: running gulp won't be successful as this is still work in progress.

Comment: I don't think you can import Angular 1 as modules, because they're not declared as modules.

Comment: You can by using type definition files. Check out `src/client/types/libs` folder

Comment: Have you tried `import * as angular from './src/client/types/libs/angular/angular'`to get your angular variable?

Comment: No, but I should not have to do it. VS Code should be aware of this variable on its own.

Comment: I don't think it is, it only knows when you import or use the /// references as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, I do, and unless I place the reference thing my angular variable is not getting recognized.

Had a quick look. This https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/ng-boilerplate/pull/3 should fix it. Basically `/` instead of `\\`

Answer (score 1):

You need to actual export the individual "angular modules" from your files, then import them into your master app.js file. When you import them as module dependencies to Ngular, just add .name at the end. (Returns the actual string name of it)

```
MyModule.name // after being imported to master app.js file


// when exporting, export the entire module not just the class controller

var homeModule = angular
    .module('app.home')
    .directive('home', homeDirective);

export = homeModule;
```

Comment: the issue is not with the module, but with the `angular` variable is not recognized the moment you remove `/// reference` thing. There is also not going to be master `app.js` file since I'm going to be loading files on demand using requirejs. But that's irrelevant. I'm not trying to run the project. Just open project in VSC and you'll see that `angular` variables are underlined with red.